# How do I determine if an SSD fits into my tablet/notebook?

Tags: ssd, thinkpad

I have a [Lenovo X220 Tablet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004URCFPM). My question is: How do I determine if an SSD, e.g. [this OCZ Octane SATA III SSD](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ocz-octane-sata-iii-2-5-ssd.html/) will fit?

Comment: The answer you seek will be in the manuals. Just take the Lenovo's manual, read it and see how big a drive fits. Then look up the size of the SSD.

Comment: http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/pdf/system_data/x220_tech_specs.pdf There's your Datasheet.  All available drives for that series are tagged as 7mm high.  The drive you want to use is 9.3mm high.  So, the drive is too big for the bay.

Comment: actually, @BonGart not true. i have an X220, and a 9mm drive will fit just fine - however, you will not be using the "drive sled" that the 7mm drives fit into. remove your existing drive, and just stick the SSD in. it will be snug, but it wont require force, and will be snug enough that movement and vibration are not a big deal. (lenovo X220 w/ OCZ vertex3 SSD here)

Comment: I have put a hard drive that was thinner, into a laptop built for a thicker hard drive. I just took a strip of paper and folded it multiple times until it was a thick cuboid 1cm by 1cm by a growing thickness. And I used that to fill the space. That way the thinner hard drive would be snug and not rattle.

Answer (score 3):

1. Visit the website of the company that manufactured your table/notebook/netbook and look up your product.

   [image]
2. Look up the product specifications or try to find a data sheet.

   [image]
3. Look for information regarding your drive bays and what size drive fits into them.

   [image]

If the available information is insufficient, you should try to reach the company that manufactured your product directly. They will usually know best what other components their products are compatible with.

Personally, I would always recommend looking for some sort of live chat feature on their website.

[image]

If that is not available, look for alternative support options to contact them.

[image]