# Zen ultrabook ux32v and disk drive

Tags: ssd, asus-laptop, ultrabook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine if an SSD fits into my tablet/notebook?](https://superuser.com/questions/461046/how-do-i-determine-if-an-ssd-fits-into-my-tablet-notebook)

I just bought a Zen ultrabook from Asus. very exciting to get my hands on one, and I did not give it much of a tought but I allready have a 256 GB SSD drive which I tought I could stuff in it, but this computer seems very thin and wonder if this 2.5" SSD drive will fit in?... before I break any guarantee I just like to know if anyone here has any experience with such machine and changing to a SSD drive...

it already have a 24 gb SSD but I think it does not really help much ??

Comment: without looking at any specs... I can safely say that it is either going to fit into the drive bay, or it is not.  There will not be any "stuffing" involved.  Yes, some computers have limited drive bay space, and it is possible that the height of the drive bay is smaller than the drive you want to put in there.  But if you attempted to do so, and it did not slide in easily, then you don't force it.  You then know the drive is taller than the bay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some basic research on the net, e.g. see [Notebook review forum](http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus/659073-ivy-bridge-zenbook-fhd-ips-screen-ux21a-ux31a-ux32a-ux32vd-51.html), shows that some ASUS UX32 v models uses proprietary connectors. If this is the case, you will not be able to add/change to the other SSD.

Comment: thanks ! I opened it, and it seems I did not violate any sticker that says I break waranty. I successfully changed drive, reinstalled however there was only one extra slot to install memory. 2 gb allready soldered on motherboard so 4 + 2 gave me 6 gb of ram, better for now. :)